# Varargs and Generics in java

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

Consider the following scenario:

```
<T> void function(T...args){
   ...code...
}
```

And then I call it using a `Integer[]`.  How does the compiler assume that `T` is an `Integer`, and not a `Integer[]`?  (Note, I'm glad that this is the case, but I still find the ambiguity odd).

Furthermore, if I wanted `T` to be `Integer[]`, is there anyway for me to do that (assuming boxing/unboxing doesn't exist)?

Comment: T is from `int[]` type, not `int`. Change your array to `Integer`.

Comment: Actually, it would not be `int`, but `Integer`.

Comment: @Darkhogg it won't be `Integer` but `int[]`.

Comment: Ah you guys are right, let me edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java compiler is smart enough to know that, since you gave it an `Integer[]`, you probably meant for `T` to be `Integer`, not `Integer[]`. I'd assume this is part of the Java language specification that defines `...` as varargs.

If you want to specify what `T` is, you can do that with the following syntax:

```
Integer[] ary = { 1, 2, 3 };
myObj.function(ary); // T is Integer
myObj.<Integer>function(ary); // T is Integer
myObj.<Integer[]>function(ary); // T is Integer[]


<Integer>function(ary); // this is invalid; instead you could do...
this.<Integer>function(ary); // this if it's an instance method
MyClass.<Integer>function(ary); // or this if it's static
```

Comment: +1 since this is the first time I find a real use case to declare the type of `T` when calling a method.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza as opposed to the rampant non-real use-cases that arise due to pathetic type inference.

Answer (score 1):

Generics works on object references, so `<T>` will work on object references of a class. `int[]` is a class that references an array of `int`, while `int` is a primitive. `Integer[]` is a class that references to an array of `Integer`, where `Integer` is another class.

After reviewing this, the varargs param `T ... args` expects an array of object references, so `int[]` would be a single element in the array of object references, while `Integer[]` is an array of object references.

If you want to send an `Integer[]` as each element of your varargs, you can send an `Integer[][]`. I wrote an example:

```
public class SomeMain {

    static <T> void foo(T...ts) {
        for(T t : ts) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };
        Integer[] integers = { 1, 2, 3 };
        foo(ints);
        foo(integers);
        //note, here each element in the varags will behave as Integer[]
        foo(new Integer[][] { integers });
    }
}
```

Output (the hash code of the array will change on every run):

```
[I@8dc8569

1
2
3

[Ljava.lang.Integer;@45bab50a
```

Comment: I didn't mean `int[]` array, but rather an `Integer[]` array. (or any `Object[]` array for that matter)

Comment: @MrTi I added the `int[]` explanation just for other readers to help understanding this problem. You didn't even realized until you started reading the comments (or at least that's what you showed to me).

Comment: That last idea is a genius one. However, if I understand you right, the varargs function expects an array first, then multiple parameters second?

Comment: @MrTi varargs is, in the end, an array. So you should end sending an array or multiple elements and wait for the compiler to make an array from them.

Comment: So, it effectively checks each of the functions, see if it's an array, and if it can't, then checks to see if it can make an array. (Basically what I said earlier, but in more explicit terms)

Comment: @MrTi just to note, if there are two methods `foo(Integer[] arg)` and `foo(T...args)` and you call `foo(new Integer[]{ 1, 2, 3})` the first will be called instead of the varargs one.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 phases in finding the applicable methods. On the 1st phase, javac tries to match argument types and method parameter types exactly. The parameter type of the method is `T[]`  on this phase, the argument type is `Integer[]`, the two matche after `T` is inferred to be `Integer`, therefore the method is chosen as *the* applicable method (there are no other overloading methods to consider). No further phases are carried out.

If the 1st phase does not yield an applicable method, javac will continue to other phases. For example, if `T` is explicitly specified as `Integer[]`, the method will not match on the 1st phase (because `T[]` would not match `Integer[]`)

On the 3rd phase, varargs are considered; javac will match `T`, not `T[]`, with trailing argument types.

This is indeed, quite confusing, and appear to be ambiguous to our intuition.

Comment: Where are these phases described? I'd love to read up on them.

Comment: there are 40 pages in java language spec to explain method invocation expression:) see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

Answer (score 0):

Note that Generics isn't completely relevant to the question. The exact same question would apply if the function signature were `void function(Object... args)` -- if you pass an expression of type `Integer[]`, it could interpreted as either using the array as `args`, or as one of the elements of `args`.

The answer is that, basically, the compiler will prefer to use the argument as `args` if possible. Since the expression you are passing has "array of reference type" type, it is compatible with `args`, and therefore, that interpretation prevails.

> Furthermore, if I wanted T to be Integer[], is there anyway for me to
>   do that (assuming boxing/unboxing doesn't exist)?

Since it is a generic method, you can explicitly specify the the type argument when calling: `this.<Integer[]>function(...)`.

But back to the more general question where the function signature is `void function(Object... args)`. You could explicitly create the array of arguments yourself:

```
function(new Integer[][]{ myIntegerArray });
```

or (simpler) you can cast the expression to a type that is no longer an array of reference type:

```
function((Object)myIntegerArray);
```